# glutPostRedisplay() causing extreme lag when drawing in GLUT

Tags: c++, line, glut, lag

I am using GLUT to draw a sequence of lines and my `glutPassiveMotionFunc(passiveMotion);` (no button press mouse motion) draws a line from the end of the line sequence to wherever the cursor is. This project is intended to be a bezier curve tool so I also render tangents with `glutMotionFunc(motion);` (button hold mouse motion). At this stage there are `drawLine()` calls at every place the cursor is in the window. I call `glutPostRedisplay();`to refresh the screen at the end of each movement to get rid of the history of `drawLine()` calls.

The introduction of `glutPostRedisplay();` makes the program lag more and more each time my display function `glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);` renders a line segment.

```
void myMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) 
{
    // If left button was clicked
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON)
    {
        if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
        {
            Point point;
            point.setxy(x, SCREEN_HEIGHT - y);
            // Draw the red  dot.
            glColor3f(255, 0, 0);
            drawDot(point);
            pointsVector[0] = point;
            points++;
            pointsVector[points].setxy((float)x, (float)(SCREEN_HEIGHT - y));
            glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
            drawLine(pointsVector[points - 1], pointsVector[points]);
        }
        else if (state == GLUT_UP)
        {
            Handle.setxy(x, SCREEN_HEIGHT - y);
            controlPoints[0] = pointsVector[0];
            controlPoints[points].setxy(Handle.x, Handle.y);
            glColor3f(0, 255, 0);
            drawDot(Handle);

            reverseControlPoints[0] = pointsVector[0];
            ReverseHandle.x = (2 * pointsVector[points].x) - Handle.x;
            ReverseHandle.y = (2 * pointsVector[points].y) - Handle.y;
            reverseControlPoints[points].setxy(ReverseHandle.x, ReverseHandle.y);
            glColor3f(0, 255, 0);
            drawDot(ReverseHandle);

            glColor3f(0, 0, 255);
            drawLine(Handle, ReverseHandle);
        }
    }
}

void passiveMotion(int x, int y)
{
    Point Cursor;
    Cursor.setxy(x, SCREEN_HEIGHT - y);
    if ((pointsVector[0].x != NULL) && (pointsVector[0].y != NULL))
    {
        drawLine(pointsVector[points], Cursor);
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}

void motion(int x, int y)
{
    Point Cursor;
    Cursor.setxy(x, SCREEN_HEIGHT - y);
    //drawLine(pointsVector[points], Cursor);
    Point reverseCursor;
    reverseCursor.x = (2 * pointsVector[points].x) - Cursor.x;
    reverseCursor.y = (2 * pointsVector[points].y) - Cursor.y;
    drawLine(pointsVector[points], reverseCursor);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void myDisplay() 
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    for (int i = 1; i < points; i++)
    {
        // draw main line & dot
        glColor3f(255, 0, 0);
        drawDot(pointsVector[i]);
        glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
        drawLine(pointsVector[i], pointsVector[i + 1]);

        // draw tangent lines and tangent dots
        glColor3f(0, 255, 0);
        drawLine(controlPoints[i + 1], reverseControlPoints[i + 1]);
        glColor3f(0, 0, 255);
        drawDot(controlPoints[i + 1]);
        drawDot(reverseControlPoints[i + 1]);
    }
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 150);
    glutCreateWindow("Bezier Curve");
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
    glutMouseFunc(myMouse);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(passiveMotion);
    glutMotionFunc(motion);
    myInit();
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say for sure, however this snippet inside your display function looks suspicious.

```
controlPoints.push_back(Handle);
reverseControlPoints.push_back(ReverseHandle);
```

I don't know what Handle is exactly, however it seems like you're inserting new copies of it into your vectors with every frame, and I don't see you ever clearing them out. Also in `myMouse()` you're incrementing `points` which you then use to iterate through that ever-expanding vector. From my memory of how GLUT works, [unless you explicitly set it to not repeat button presses,](https://linux.die.net/man/3/glutsetkeyrepeat) `myMouse()` won't fire just once when you click a mouse button, it will instead keep triggering the callback while you have it held down. Which means more increments to `points`, more eventual iterations through the vectors, and slower and slower code.

Comment: I implemented your suggestions and updated my question entirely. After some troubleshooting it is `glutPostRedisplay();` that is causing the lag. Do you have any corrections I could make with the function call?